# Php copy : Invalid argument error only on inside while loop and working for last record

Tags: php, copy

Reading the file for the image url and calling the copy function.

imagecopy.txt

```
https://server.com/2017/12/check.png
https://server.com/2017/12/contacts.png
https://server.com/2018/06/CDP.bmp
https://server.com/module-acculturation-1.png
```

While copying the files from the url, getting the failed to open stream: Invalid argument error only on inside while loop. but works for the last record if the file has more files.

```
   <?php
$file=fopen("imagecopy.txt","r") or exit("Unable to open file!");
while (!feof($file))
{
    $source = fgets($file);
    $imagename = explode("/", $source);
    $pathname = 'uploads/' . date("Y") . '/' . date("m") . '/';
    if (!is_dir($pathname)) 
    {
    mkdir($pathname, 0777, true);
    }

    $destination = $pathname.end($imagename); 
    copyimageURL($source, $destination);                  
}
fclose($file);

function copyimageURL($source, $destination)
{
    echo $source;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $destination;
    copy($source, $destination);
}

?>
```

1.Working fine with singe record
 2.Copying the last image only if the file has more images list.

Comment: `$imagename[8]` looks like it will be undefined (index) somewhen.

Comment: Updated the code with proper index position , while positing the question wrongly updated the old code. sry.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing imagecopy.txt you're reading ends in a newline, which makes the last line of the file blank.
If you change

```
$source = fgets($file);
```

to

```
$source = trim(fgets($file));
if( empty($source) ) continue;
```

it should work fine

Comment: only working for the last record. Not facing the empty data issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if ($file) {
    while (($name = fgets($file)) !== false) {
        $imagename = basename($name);
        $pathname = 'uploads/' . date("Y") . '/' . date("m") . '/';
        if (!is_dir($pathname)) 
            mkdir($pathname, 0777, true);

        $destination = $pathname.$imagename; 
        copyimageURL(trim($name), $destination);     
    }
    fclose($file);
}
```